# Titanium Alloy: How to pass array in an attribute

Tags: arrays, attributes, titanium

How to pass an array in an attribute in an attribute in alloy Xml. e.g.

```
<ImageView id="myImg" images='[\"doc.png\", \"tech.png\"]'></ImageView>
```

Comment: Have you tried to provide the property `images` with the array in tss ?

Answer (score 0):

@Sunny Luthra! The example you taken in problem is a right way to pass an array attributes of the property ***images*** of **ImageView**. Almost all the property that support the array attribute values can be defined in ***.xml*** file, but we suggest you defined them in ***.tss*** file cause there're some character parse problem may happen we should avoid. Like (@Swanand had said in his comment):

(Please note: the images property for imageView should use with a animation method to show, which should initial the first image of the imageView with **start()** function. For more details, [click here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ImageView-property-images).)

```
<ImageView id='myImg'/>  //xml

"#myImg":{               //tss
    images:['/doc.png', 'tech.png']
}
```

The situation is appropriate in ***.tss*** file, if you want a more flexible way to apply the array attributes for some property, we suggest you defined your UI component in ***.js*** file. And you can defined yourselves property for the UI component.

```
var myImg = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    key: value,                      //diy-property, the value can be a json, array, string... any attributes you want
    images:['/doc.png','/tech.png']
});
```

Maybe these can help you!